# Mysqli - OOP implementation

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

[SOLVED]

I have two classes: DB class which is a Mysqli implementation and Users class.

User class have 2 functions: get user and get users.

```
public function get_user_data($email){
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$result= $this->mydb->runQuery($query);
return $result->fetch_array();
}
```

this function works with no problem. I call it like this:

```
$userData   = $users->get_user_data($email]);
$username = $userData['nickname'];
```

The problem is in the second function that gets all users:

```
public function get_users(){
$query="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY time";
$result= $this->mydb->runQuery($query);
return $result->fetch_all();}
```

I use it like this:

```
$members = $users->get_users(); 
foreach ($members as $member) {
echo '<p>' . $member[1] . ' with email ' . $member[8]. '</p>';}
```

I want to call $members like in the first example, as members['email'] and not by order of the columns and i have read that fetch_all produce assosiative array but it doesnt work and i get an error. How should i change it so i can use it with the column names?

**ANSWER:**
What i needed to do is just to explicitly write:

```
return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

and then it works great,

Comment: Just refrain from writing OOP implementation until you get solid grip on the technology.

Comment: What a strange advice is it? How can i learn something if i dont use it and try working with it?

Comment: Because you have a lot to learn *prior* to OOP. While mixing tasks will make your mission hardly possible.

Comment: As a matter of fact, OOP alone is harder than whole PHP and Mysql at once.

Comment: First of all, i know OOP. I just never used it in PHP. The concept and implementation in other lang. are not new to me. Second - the question itself was about a specific problem, not about OOP. And the last point - best learning is being done by practicing, not by passive learning, so your advice "learn and dont write" is very strange

Comment: Well, I see that although the error turned to be not one I thunk of, the conversation made you, at last, read the function description from manual :)

Comment: " not one I thunk of" - But at least you were arrogant and didnt help at all. Its really not important what the question or the answer was.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your own OOP implementation, first try to use a ready-made one.

Say, with my safeMysql class you will get the desired result with cleaner and **safer** code:

```
public function get_user_data($email)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?s";
    return $this->mydb->getRow($query, $email);
}

public function get_users()
{
    return $this->mydb->getAll("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY time");
}
```

Comment: Secondly - i dont need to rewrite "get-user_data(). It works well (as i wrote in my question)

Comment: as a matter of fact, you WANT to rewrite it, due to many reasons one of them SECURITY of your application. As I told you before, you have a lot to learn

Comment: As of fetch_all() function, I am pretty sure you know the reason already, which is brought to you by PHP

Comment: Can you please explain what is "getAll"? I didnt see it in MySQLI functions... What is unclean in my code? How to get it better? About safety - i know that i am not using prepared statements. I will update the code with them afterwards

Comment: Please, re-read my answer *whole*. It is clearly stated there, what getAll function is.

Comment: "as a matter of fact, you WANT to rewrite it, due to many reasons one of them SECURITY of your application." - what is the exact problem with my code? The fact that i dont use prepared statements?

Comment: yes, the fact that you dont use prepared statements

Comment: Ok, got it with the security problem... For now, security is not a problem i need to face and i know how to repair it. The question is about how getting all the answers in a associative array. Maybe i am very slow but no, i didnt understand from your answer or from PHP, why fetch all doesnt work because i read that "The mysqli_fetch_all() function fetches all result rows and returns the result-set as an associative array, a numeric array, or both."

Comment: May I ask you a question? Why you refuse to read the error message was brought to you by PHP?

Comment: Why do you think that i "refuse" to read it? And why your answers sounds so arrogant? It seems you forgot the time when you were young and un-experinced and just started with a new lang... You could just tell me the answer (that i wrote in my question). People like you dont help, they kill the desire to learn and to ask questions.

Comment: Simply because I see no effect this error message caused on your actions. *May be* it is not me being the reason of your problems

Comment: I don't have problems. I had a simple question. Instead of helping, you showed your arrogance and lectured me about things i didn't ask. This is not the way to help someone learn. Fortunately i have found the answer and learned that even in this awesome community there are people whose  goal is to show that they know things instead of sharing and explaining. Have a good day...